# memory paging with D

Tags: memory, paging, d, tango

I'm using D/Tango for catalog indexing, is there any library to aid with memory (RAM) paging for a dictionary which is in memory and can go up to 10gb while performing indexing?

Comment: D echoed to the D newsgroup: http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?art_group=digitalmars.D.learn&article_id=16999

Answer (score 1):

What kind of aid do you need?

If you simply allocate the memory, operating system will take care of paging automatically.

If you want on-disk structure, then use memory mapped file.